# How to determine $\int e^{2x} \sqrt{e^x+1}dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

Determine

$\int e^{2x} \sqrt{e^x+1}dx$

Is there a multiplication rule for integration or something?

Answer (score 3):

$$\int e^{2x} \sqrt{e^x+1}dx=\int (e^x\sqrt{e^x+1})e^xdx$$
$e^x+1=t,e^xdx=dt,e^x=t-1$
$$\int e^{2x}\sqrt{e^x+1}dx=\int(t-1)\sqrt tdt=\int t^{3/2}dt-\int t^{1/2}dt=$$
$$=\frac{t^{3/2+1}}{3/2+1}-\frac{t^{1/2+1}}{1/2+1}+C=\frac{2}{5}(e^x+1)^{5/2}-\frac{2}{3}(e^x+1)^{3/2}+C$$

Comment: i dont understand this

Comment: Do you understand now.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: $$\sqrt{e^x+1}=u\implies e^x+1=u^2$$

Comment: U-Sub?‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏

Comment: @Hello, Yes, any confusion?

Comment: I get to $2\sqrt{e^x+1}$. Now what?

Comment: @Hello, $\int e^{2x} \sqrt{e^x+1}dx=\int(u^2-1)u\ 2udu$

Comment: How do you do that?

Comment: @Hello, $$e^x-1=u^2\implies e^xdx=2u\ du, e^x=u^2-1$$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16767/discussion-between-hello-and-lab-bhattacharjee).